# By using tablesorter how to specify th td size?

Tags: php, jquery, tablesorter

**I am  using below code**

```
<table class="tablesorter custom-popup"><thead><tr>
 <th class="filter-false"   data-sorter="false"></th> 
   <th>Host</th><th>Status</th><th>place</th>           
  <th>Local Content</th><th>user</th><th>Drive</th>
  <th>Capable</th><th>Test</th><th>Customer</th><th ">Info</th>
```

For this columns th info and local Conttent has the two words of the data.That time also 
th displaying very big.I need to restrict specific columns th td size.

Any solutions is appreciable.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To limit column widths, set the column size using css

Do this either by adding class names to each column:

HTML

```
<th class="filter-false narrow" data-sorter="false"></th>
<th class="host">Host</th>
<th class="status">Status</th>
<!-- ... -->
<th class="info">Info</th>
```

CSS

```
.narrow { width: 25px; }
.host { width: 100px; }
.status { width: 50px; }
/* ... */
.info { width: 100px; }
```

Or using pure css (you only need to target one header row)

```
.custom-popup th:nth-child(1) { width: 25px; }
.custom-popup th:nth-child(2) { width: 100px; }
.custom-popup th:nth-child(3) { width: 50px; }
/* ... */
.custom-popup th:nth-child(11) { width: 100px; }
```

Alternatively, you can add a `<col>` with a defined width inside a `<colgroup>`

```
<table class="tablesorter custom-popup">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:25px">
    <col style="width:100px">
    <col style="width:50px">
    <!-- ... -->
    <col style="width:100px">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <!-- ... -->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- ... -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can I apply this css for one column and reaming columns default behavior is possible?

Comment: Yes, just target the one column.